# Применение нескольких классов стилей к одному єлементу (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Доброй ночи всем.
Столкнулся с проблемой: не применяються два класса к одному элементу. Хотя вычитал, что для применения достаточно просто разделить их названия пробелом.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

```
 <html>
 <head> 
 <title>Популярность браузеров в мире</title>
 <style>
    TABLE { 
         border-collapse: collapse; 
         background: dimgrey;         
    }
    TD, TH {
         padding: 0.5em; 
     }
     .rightSide {
         text-align: right;
     }
    TR.even {
         background: silver;
     }
    TR.sameHeight {
         height: 50px;
    }
 </style>
</head>
  <body>
  <table id = "browser_stats">
       <tr class = "sameHeight"> <th>Год\Бpayзep</th> <th>IE</th><th>Firefox</th><th>Safari</th><th>Opera</th> </tr>   
   <tr class = "even" class = "sameHeight"> <td class = "rightSide">2010</td><td>61.43%</td><td>24.40%</td><td>4.55%</td><td>2.37%</td> </tr> 
   <tr class = "sameHeight"> <td class = "rightSide">2009</td><td>69.13%</td><td>22.67%</td><td>3.58%</td><td>2.18%</td> </tr>
   <tr class = "even" class = "sameHeight"> <td class = "rightSide">2008</td><td>77.83%</td><td>16.86%</td><td>2.65%</td><td>1.84%</td> </tr> 
   <tr class = "sameHeight"> <td class = "rightSide">2007</td><td>79.38%</td><td>14.35%</td><td>4.70%</td><td>0.50%</td> </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: после д обавления классов ничего не происхоит

Comment: class не так пишется :   <tr class = "even" class = "sameHeight">   а так :  <tr class = "even sameHeight">

Comment: Вам тоже спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишите CLASS="1класс 2класс" а не отдельно

```
class = "even" class = "sameHeight" >>> class = "even sameHeight"
```

Comment: спасибо) теперь понятно, как "писать через пробел")